# passing ‘const this argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: gcc, g++

I have a class `Cache` which has a function write specified as

```
bool write(const MemoryAccess &memory_access, CacheLine &cl);
```

I am calling this function like this.

```
const Cache *this_cache;
c = (a==b)?my_cache:not_cache;
c->write(memory_access,cl);
```

The above line is giving me following error

> "passing ‘const Cache’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool Cache::write(const
>   MemoryAccess&, CacheLine&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]."

the this argument is compiler specific which helps in code-mangling and breaking local namespace variable priority. But such a variable is not being passed here.

Comment: Please try to fix your example: you talk about function `write`, then you call `read`. Where do you declare `memory_access` and `cl`?

Comment: *the this argument is compiler specific which helps in code-mangling and breaking local namespace variable priority*???

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since `c` is of type `const Cache *`, you can only call `const` member functions on it.

You have two options:

(1) remove `const` from the declaration of `c`;

(2) change `Cache::write()` like so:

```
 bool write(const MemoryAccess &memory_access, CacheLine &cl) const;
```

(Note the added `const` at the end.)

Comment: what is the significance of const at the end of the signature ?? What exactly do we mean when we say this is constant. Should it not be constant by default ??

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10

Answer (score 5):

When you call a method via a pointer to an object, this object is implicitly passed to the method as `this` pointer. `c` probably has type `const Cache*`. Since method `write` is not declared as `const`, it has non-const `this` pointer accessible from its body requiring `const` qualifier of `c` to be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Also if your class's method returns pointer on any member you shouldn't forget write const before returning type example:

`const float * getPosition() const{...}`