# error: passing ‘const std::map<int, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

Fetching an entry from a const C++ std::map fails to compile on gcc 5.4.0.

```
test_map.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_map.cpp:9:24: error: passing ‘const std::map<int, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                 foo[key];
```

### Minimal test case

```
// Compile with
// g++ test_map.cpp -o test_map

#include <map>

int main() {
    const std::map<int, int> foo;
    foo[0]; // compiles if "const" above is suppressed
}
```

### Look before you post

This looks similar to [passing ‘const this argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765787/passing-const-this-argument-discards-qualifiers-fpermissive) which is about a `Cache`, not a `std::map`.  The cause there: the user calls a `write()` method. That method is not declared `const` which makes sense since writing presumably modified the object.

But here, fetching an element from a map does not modify the map, does it?

### Question

The actual map in my real use case is indeed const.  It's fully initialized in the source code.  It does not make sense to modify it.  Declaring it non-const practically solves the problem but does not make sense.

Comment: `operator[]` does not fetch anything from a map, it returns a mutable reference to a value in the map. As such, it cannot be used in a `const` map instance.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik more importantly, it inserts a value if the key isn't present. That's why it can't be used on a const map.

Comment: _But here, fetching an element from a map does not modify the map, does it?_ Did you even try to read the documentation?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Your comment is the best answer. Also, an access operator that inserts elements seems one of the silliest things in a language such as C++ where things aims to be minimal, memory and cpu-parsimonius and you're supposed to pay only for what you use. Even C# has this right. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have searched for relevant keywords and phrases in Google then in stackexchange itself, have read several questions and answers (probably 5 or 6), but surprisingly the pre-existing question did not show up at the time.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon Yes, unfortunately it is easy to find duplicates... if you already know the answer.

Comment: I do not find @StéphaneGourichon posed a stupid question at all, and I do not think it is a duplicate: It wasn't directly clear to me either that `operator[]` cannot be used an `const` map instances.

The error message returned also differs from the 5+ other "similar" questions: Note that there is no specification of the `argument`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`operator[]` doesn't have a `const` qualifier in `std::map`, as you can see from the documentation, e.g. [std::map::operator[] - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

Therefore you cannot use it directly on a `const` instance. Use `at` instead (ref [std::map::at - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at)) if you can afford C++11 features.

Declarations for those member functions follow:

```
T& operator[](const key_type& x);
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
T&       at(const key_type& x);
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
```

Comment: I forgot in C++ map, looking up a key that does not exist added the key to the map.  Makes sense in some context, but not obvious to me!  Ty for this answer now I understand this error I'm also hitting.